# Cant Get SolidColor value of ArtLayers in Photoshop w/ PHP COM Interface

Tags: php, com, photoshop

I am trying to get color values of SolidColor (or sometimes SolidFill) ArtLayers like this:

```
$app = new \COM('Photoshop.Application');
$doc = $app->ActiveDocument;
foreach ($doc->ArtLayers as $layer) {
    if ($layer->Kind == 3) { // which means Solid Color Layer
        echo $layer->Name.': '.$layer->SolidColor;
    }
}
```

I tried many way like $layer->Color, $layer->FillColor, $layer->Fill->Color etc as methods or property, always throws error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Unable to lookup `Color'
```

or

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method variant::Color()
```

There is no documentation for this; get_object_vars, get_class_methods etc always return empty array, or throws error, Photoshop keeps silence what it have in itself...

How to get/set SolidColor ArtLayer in Photoshop with PHP Com Class? How to find a correct way to get over all errors?

Comment: Wow, COM and Photoshop, it has been a while for me. Do you at least have the [VBS reference handy](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/blob/master/Documentation/Product%20specific%20Documentation/Photoshop%20Scripting/photoshop-vbs-ref-2020.pdf)? Can you try inspecting `$layer->typename` to see if there's a class that might be more descriptive? I'm guessing it will come back as an ArtLayer still, but worth trying.

Comment: $layer->typename return only "ArtLayer" string. I got JS PDF, but ways are forking with com class and other languages... Trying to understand possibilities with https://github.com/lohriialo/photoshop-scripting-python

Comment: A long time ago, for ASP or VBS scripting, we’d import the DLL (or maybe IDL file?) into Visual Studio, just to get breakpoints so we could inspect the object at runtime. I don’t know if that’s an option anymore, however. We’d still write in whatever language, that was sometimes the best way to see the object model which didn’t always align with the documentation.

Comment: Photoshop COM API has a very demanding work environment; Adobe has developed many products that work with this API, but they're all a bit incomplete and lacking in documentation. With miracles and hardwork I solved the problems. Thank you for attention; developers lucky someday in the lonely roads :)

Comment: If you solved the problem, it would be useful to answer your own question with the solution so that others may benefit from it

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Yes it is solved, but not easy to explain. Also, you are right: soon I will try to leave an answer/explaination. Thank you for remembering.